# 'Errno::EPROTO' vagrant cache clear issue rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, caching, vagrant, asset-pipeline

After precompile assets I have error like this:

> Protocol error @ rb_file_s_stat - /vagrant/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets/v3.0/Wi/Wi2PVgUy27cBt2eSmCKh9XhnqGbUY7TNL23vbec1LJY.cache

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track':'reload' %>
```

I`ve already tried:

- rake tmp:cache:clear
- rake assets:clobber
- rm -rf tmp mkdir /tmp/rails-app ln -s /tmp/rails-app tmp

Does anyone known how to resolve that issue ?